# Create static singleton instance different for each user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web, static, singleton

I am developing a web site using ASP.NET MVC and I have a lot of instructions like this one:

```
new ReleaseFactory().BuildFeatureSection();
```

To improve the code I thought to use static methods:

```
ReleaseFactory.BuildFeatureSection()
```

The problem is that I am afraid of the possibility to occur a deadlock.

These methods often access to different data sources (such as Excel documents, databases, etc), and as far as I know is not a good idea to access them through static methods, especially when developing a web application.

Any good idea to improve the current syntax?

Edit: Some more information about the purpose of Release Factory.

ReleaseFactory is a class used to create the ViewModels for the Release page. The data displayed are not based on the logged user, but are the same for everybody. In my web site there are other Factories with a constructor which needs usually just one parameter.

E.g.: {baseUrl}/Feature/{ID}

```
public ActionResult BetaProgram(int id)
{  
       var viewModel = new FeatureFactory(id).BuildFeatureViewModel();

       return View(viewModel);
}
```

Also in this case the displayed information is not based on the user, but just on the id of the current page. Hope this helps to understand better the situation.

Comment: "To improve the code" - How so? What issue are you trying to solve? It seems to me like you're adding problems rather than solving them.

Comment: `ThreadStaticAttribute` if each user has it separate thread

Comment: @DmitryBychenko "Thread" is almost never a synonym of "user" in an ASP.NET application.

Comment: Your question is valid, but the title certainly threw me off.

Comment: @dcastro - that's why he said "IF each user has a separate thread"

Comment: @dcastro Personally I think a good code should be shorter as possible, withouth ruins the readibility. So, the second example (ReleaseFactory.BuildFeatureSection()) is better that the current code.

Comment: Note though that thread <> User or even request. [ThreadStatic will cause problems in an Asp.Net application.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ATaleOfTwoTechniquesTheThreadStaticAttributeAndSystemWebHttpContextCurrentItems.aspx)

Comment: @DeeMac You're right, sorry but I didn't know how to explain the problem. Feel free to edit the title if you any idea to improve it.

Comment: @simoneL Saving 3 characters and a pair of parenthesis isn't much of a win. Especially when you have to radically change the semantics of the code in order to save those characters. Clearly, if each users has to have its own resources, then the resources are not meant to be static at all. If the current code meets your requirements, then I would personally leave it be. I don't see anything wrong with it (other than its not coding against an interface, the factory should be injected into the controller).

Comment: There is missing information, such as how `ReleaseFactory` depends on the current user. For example I don't see any parameter in its constructor.

Comment: Added some information in the open post. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, my best advice would be to use locking e.g.

```
public static class Foo
{
    private static object lockingObject = new object();

    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        lock (lockingObject)
        {
            // Do your stuff.
        }
    }
}
```

This is a simple example, which may suffice for you, not sure. Basically you are blocking access to the code running inside the `lock` statement to one thread at a time. This could eliminate deadlocking, since only one thread at a time can execute the code in the `lock` statement.

Your best bet is to try this and, if you have the tools, do some load testing on the code, see what breaks.